# Posting data in a Spring Boot 2 Application with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to post data from postman via my Spring Boot 2 Application with Spring Data JPA into a MySQL Database. All I get is a 404 Error.

Main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProfileApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProfileApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
public @Data class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String profileText;
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public class ProfileController {

    @Autowired
    private ProfileRepository profileRepository;

    public ProfileRepository getRepository() {
        return profileRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/profile/{id}")
    Profile getProfileById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return profileRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    @PostMapping("/profile")
    Profile createOrSaveProfile(@RequestBody Profile newProfile) {
        return profileRepository.save(newProfile);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile, Long> {

}
```

application.propterties

```
server.port = 8080
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/profiledb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
server.servlet.context-path=/service
```

[image]

Comment: Have you run your mysql server instance locally on your machine?

Comment: Please add also the curl or screenshot of postman to the question.

Comment: @MohsenAbasi MySQL is tunnint locally.

Comment: 404 means that can't find the api you're calling. Perhaps your using the wrong path.

Comment: Take a look at @Alexandru Somai answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in your `ProfileController`, you have defined twice the `profile` endpoint (first at the class level, and second on the methods). The solution would be to remove one of them:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public class ProfileController {

    @Autowired
    private ProfileRepository profileRepository;

    public ProfileRepository getRepository() {
        return profileRepository;
    }

    // Notice that I've removed the 'profile' from here. It's enough to have it at class level
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    Profile getProfileById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return profileRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    // Notice that I've removed the 'profile' from here. It's enough to have it at class level
    @PostMapping
    Profile createOrSaveProfile(@RequestBody Profile newProfile) {
        return profileRepository.save(newProfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: If he wants to call /service/profile/profile it's not an error (even if is terrible talking about api design).

Comment: You are right. Since he didn't mention the request he made, I assumed he wanted to call only `/service/profile`. (I'll update my answer to include that)

Comment: I implemented your edited code @AlexandruSomai. And it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Which url? Valid url must look like:

GET: http://localhost:8080/service/profile/profile/1

POST: http://localhost:8080/service/profile/profile